# Remove repository added with add-apt-repository

Tags: linux

I am installing Microsoft SQL Server for Linux, and I accidentally added the repository for the wrong version of Linux (I wanted the 20.04 one) with `sudo add-apt-repository "$(wget -qO- https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/18.04/mssql-server-2019.list)"`. How can I undo the result of the above line?

Answer (score 2):

you can remove it like this :

`sudo add-apt-repository -r "$(wget -qO- https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/18.04/mssql-server-2019.list)"`